Prove that Levi-Civita tensor density is invariant
I am struggling with Exercise 7.14 ( the latter part ) of the textbook Supergravity ( by Freedman and Proeyen ). Here is the problem:
We are defining the Levi-Civita form in coordiante basis as:
$$ \varepsilon^{\mu_1 \mu_1 ... \mu_D} \equiv e\ \varepsilon^{a _1 a _2 ... a _D}\ e^{\mu _1} _{a _1} e^{\mu _2} _{a _2} ... e^{\mu _D} _{a _D} \tag{7.46} $$
Here e is the determinant of $ e^a _\mu $ . The symbol $ \varepsilon $ on the RHS is totally antisymmetric symbol which can be used to compute determinant of matrix A as:
$$ det\ A\ \varepsilon_{b _1 b _2 ... b _D} = \varepsilon _{a _1 a _2 ... a _D} A ^{a _1} _{b _1} A ^{a _2} _{b _2} ... A ^{a _D} _{b _D} \tag{7.45}$$
Now we have to show that $ \delta \varepsilon^{\mu_1 \mu_1 ... \mu_D} = 0 $ for any $ \delta e ^\mu _a $.
The problem asks us to make use to the general matrix formula:
$$ \delta\ det\ M = ( det\ M)\ Tr(M ^{-1} \delta M ) \tag{7.47}$$
In our case, I can utilized eq. ( 7.47 ) to write:
$$ \delta e = e\ e ^\mu _a\ (\delta e ) ^a _\mu $$
Now I can act with $\delta$ on equation (7.46) and I will get ( since the $\varepsilon$ symbol on RHS is just invariant ):
$$ \delta \varepsilon^{\mu_1 \mu_1 ... \mu_D} =  \varepsilon^{a _1 a _2 ... a _D} [ (\delta e)\ e ^{\mu_1} _{a_1}\ e ^{\mu_2} _{a_2}\ ... e ^{\mu_D} _{a_D}\ +  e\ (\delta e ^{\mu_1} _{a_1})\ e ^{\mu_2} _{a_2}\ ... e ^{\mu_D} _{a_D}\ + ... + e\ e ^{\mu_1} _{a_1}\ e ^{\mu_2} _{a_2}\ ... (\delta e ^{\mu_D} _{a_D})\ ] \tag{A}$$
Substituting $ \delta e $  and factoring out a common e then gives:
$$ \delta \varepsilon^{\mu_1 \mu_1 ... \mu_D} =  \varepsilon^{a _1 a _2 ... a _D}\ e\ [ e ^\mu _a\ (\delta e ) ^a _\mu \ e ^{\mu_1} _{a_1}\ e ^{\mu_2} _{a_2}... e ^{\mu_D} _{a_D}\ +   (\delta e ^{\mu_1} _{a_1})\ e ^{\mu_2} _{a_2}... e ^{\mu_D} _{a_D}\ + ... +  e ^{\mu_1} _{a_1}\ e ^{\mu_2} _{a_2}... (\delta e ^{\mu_D} _{a_D})\ ] \tag{B}$$
I want to show that the RHS is zero. For this, the book again gives the hint to use the so called "Schouten identity" which ( I think ) means that if I try to make a D+1 rank tensor fully antisymmetric in D dimensions, then it will vanish. One such example for D=4 has been given in this book as:
$$ 0 = 5 \delta _\mu ^{\ [ \nu } \varepsilon ^{\rho\sigma\tau\lambda]} =  \delta _\mu ^{\ \ \nu } \varepsilon ^{\rho\sigma\tau\lambda} + \delta _\mu ^{\ \ \rho } \varepsilon ^{\sigma\tau\lambda\nu} + \delta _\mu ^{\ \ \sigma } \varepsilon ^{\tau\lambda\nu\rho} + \delta _\mu ^{\ \ \tau } \varepsilon ^{\lambda\nu\rho\sigma} + \delta _\mu ^{\ \ \lambda } \varepsilon ^{\nu\rho\sigma\tau}   \tag{3.11}$$
This seems somewhat similar to the RHS of the equation (B), but not quite. And this is where I am stuck. Can anyone help me see how the RHS of (B) vanishes? Or maybe I made a mistake even earlier.
